# Why am I seeing home in 2 different partitions

Tags: partitioning, mount

I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.04LTS dual boot configuration. I'm about to move to 16.04LTS as a fresh install not an upgrade.

At present Ubuntu sits within an extended partition (sda3) containing 4 logical partitions; sda5 mounted at /*boot*, sda6 mounted at /*home*, sda8 mounted at /*root* & sda7 as Swap.

I ran `sudo grub-fstest /dev/sda8 ls /` to see what was in the `/root` partition & found that there was a `/home` folder in there. This confused me as *home* is also a sub folder within sda6.

Why does *home* appear to be in 2 partitions at the same time.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -f`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is root's home folder.
By default, root login is disabled in Ubuntu.
So mounting  a partition for /root is unnecessary, as it will not be used; except for root's trash.